# Swedish keyboard shortcut for Search field in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, search, keyboard-shortcuts

The keyboard shortcut that takes you to the Search field on the Google Drive main view does not work on a Swedish keyboard. On an English keyboard the shortcut is / but pressing Shift+7 on a Swedish keyboard does not work. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Crossposted to [Google Drive Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/rkJ3-Cm-Ri4;context-place=topicsearchin/drive/Swedish$20keyboard$20shortcut$20for$20Search$20field$20in$20Google$20Drive)