# Google spreadsheet equivalent of Excel's Ctrl+Semicolon on international keyboards

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

In Excel, I often use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> to enter the current date.
Is there an equivalent shortcut in Google Spreadsheets that works for international keyboards like Belgium-Dutch (nl-BE)?

Comment: [Keyboard shortcuts for Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop)

Comment: @ale: Considering the answer posted by the OP I edited the question to make clear that they are looking for a keyboard shortcut that works on an international keyboard. The linked help article on your comment just say that some keyboard shortcuts doesn't work on international keyboards.

Comment: Related: [Google drive keyboard shortcuts not working with non-US keyboard](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/114185/88163)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This must be a bug in Google. I have to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>$</kbd> for some reason (the language of my keyboard is not en-US?). Google itself doesn't mention this anywhere.

Solution was found [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/zJFMF4KxWgQ) in the [last comment](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/zJFMF4KxWgQ/A312oi75EQAJ).

Comment: Are you using a French keyboard?

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent for German keyboards is `ü`. So it's

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ü</kbd> for current **date**
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>ü</kbd> for current **time**
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>ü</kbd> for current **date and time**

Answer (score 1):

For Spanish Latin American keyboard layout:

- Insert current time
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>´</kbd>
- Insert current date
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>´</kbd>
- Insert current date and time
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>´</kbd>

Reference

- [Cómo insertar la fecha de hoy en HCG](https://www.rubenrivera.mx/2018/08/insertar-fecha-hora-1.html) (How to insert the current date on Google Sheets) Disclaimer: I'm the author of this blog article.

Answer (score 1):

For the Italian keyboard layout:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>è</kbd> for current **date**
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>è</kbd> for current **time**
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>è</kbd> for current **date and time**

Answer (score 1):

For Danish / Nordic keyboard layout:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>¨</kbd> for current **date**
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>¨</kbd> for current **time**
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>¨</kbd> for current **date and time**

Answer (score 1):

For completes, the USA keyboard layout works with:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>:</kbd> time.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>  date.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>:</kbd> is the heroic keystroke sequence to insert a datetime (time and date).

See [Keyboard accelerators, mnemonics, and shortcuts](http://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=181110) for more details.