# How to delete a built-in Google Docs keyboard shortcut

Tags: google-docs, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm a student with a minor in French, so I often use the ENG INTL keyboard to write in French. Unfortunately, the shortcut to write « » is the same as the Google Docs shortcut to change the zoom to "fit": <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>

This gets really annoying, since I like to have my zoom at 100% and it changes whenever I write « or ». I would never use the zoom to fit shortcut, so I want to find a way to just delete it. Anyone know how?

Comment: Welcome. As mentioned elsewhere, this is appears to be a known problem; I'm not sure that it is on-topic for Webapps. In any event, have you read [Google drive keyboard shortcuts not working with non-US keyboard](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/114198/196152) (both the comments and the answer)? Personally, it seems that trying to change Google shortcuts is akin to "the tail trying to wag the dog"; I should be looking more closely at how to modify your keyboard shortcut to create an alternative/unique shortcut to create « ».

Comment: Thanks! I ended up just changing my zoom to zoom to fit and adding a random comment to make the doc at a reasonable zoom. It's a bummer that there's no way to edit the Google Doc shortcuts-- I hope they change that soon!