# Shortcut to clear formatting using a Mac Spanish keyboard?

Tags: google-docs, keyboard-shortcuts

I can't find the way to type the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> combination a Mac's Spanish keyboard, because the <kbd>\</kbd> is obtained using the <kbd>option</kbd> key, and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> does not work either. Is there an alternative shortcut or another way to type <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> that I can use to clear formatting?

Comment: Related https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/114185/88163

Comment: Thanks @glorfindel for the nice formatting.